# Possible to kill/terminate a certain thread in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2013

Currently trying to hunt a potential race condition, I paused my WinForms application in the visual studio debugger.

The Threads window shows a lot of thread which one of them I suspect to be the root cause for the blocking.

[image]

I would now love to do the following:

1. Select a thread
2. Right-click the thread
3. Select "Kill thread" from the context menu

Unfortunately I found no option that would allow me to do something like that.

**My question:**

Is it possible to kill/terminate a certain thread in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger?

Comment: I found this tool, it can be useful for your request: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @StefanoBafaro Just tried it, Process Explorer, when running as Administrator seems to help!

Comment: Good! I put it as Answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft Technet I found [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) that can solve your problem.

Comment: Not the best solution on earth (since it is not integrated in VS.NET) and still a very good one :-) Thanks!

Comment: This doesnt work. Even after killing the thread in Process Explorer, in the VS debugger it shows that the thread is still around. And the `System.Threading.Thread` object for the killed thread still returns true for `IsAlive`

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to just kill a thread because the designers of the language want to avoid the following problem: your thread takes a lock, and then you kill it before it can release it... now anyone who needs that lock will get stuck.

What you have to do is use some global variable to tell the thread to stop. You have to manually, in your thread code, check that global variable and return if you see it indicates you should stop.

Please note that what you are asking is not possible as it stands.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the fact that killing a thread is a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply freeze a thread (Why would you need to exactly kill it?)[image]